# Google Sheets: VLOOKUP formula for a multi line cells range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have here a sample project, where columns `A` to `C` are in `FORM RESPONSES` TAB/SHEET and columns `D` and `E` are in `RECORDS` TAB/SHEET.

In the `RECORDS` I have a list of names, in alphabetical order, and a column for BATCHES(`E9`).

What I wish to have as an output is to AUTOMATICALLY bring/distribute the batches from `RESPONSES!B4:B` to the respective attendees in `RECORD` TAB (`E10:E`).

NOTE: The names are already available in the Google Form(Checkbox type), so the list of names in `RECORD` TAB are just the same as in the Google Form.

But the problem is, there are responses in `C4:C` that has multiple names in a single cell, and I don't know what to do anymore. hehe. I have already tried the `INDEX` and `MATCH` formulas based on how I understood it as a total beginner in Google Sheet, but it only works on the first name.

I hope that someone could help me achieve the output that I wanted to achieve.

Thank you so much and may God bless everyone!

Here's the screenshot of my sample project:

[image: Here's the screenshot of my sample project:]

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for guiding me, I have accepted your answer, and now I am trying to figure out how to upvote it. Your answer really helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: *"I am trying to figure out how to upvote it"*. Just press the up-arrow once. Although the message will say you don't have enough reputation, it will show in the future when you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D8:D,
                 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN({Respos!B3:B&"@"&SPLIT(Respos!C3:C,CHAR(10))}),"@"),
                          "select Col2, Col1 where Col2 <>'' "),2,0)))
```

*(please -as always- adjust formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

---

**Additional info** *(following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153715/google-sheets-vlookup-formula-for-a-multi-line-cells-range?noredirect=1#comment140290_153718))*

- `@` is just a symbol we use as the identifier for the `SPLIT` function.
  It could be anything like ♞ or , NOT present in our text.
- `Col1` and `Col2` are the column numbers in our query.
  Be careful because they are case sensitive. That means `col` OR `COL` will NOT work.

---

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)
- [`CHAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120)

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! It worked 100%. Thank you soooo much! May I ask, what are the two "@" and "col1" and "col2" for? and the "2" before the "0"?